# Animating roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex, animation

I have a list with complex numbers and I want to animate them. How can i do this? I would like to have appearing lines between points. I hope you know what I mean.
Here is my code:

```
 roots[re_, im_, n_] := 
     Module[{a = re, b = im, zkList, phi, zk, k, IM, RE, zkList2, p, 
       number},
      number = a + I*b;
      zkList = 
       Table[{Power[Abs[re + im*I], (
           n)^-1]*(Cos[(Arg[re + im*I] + 2*k*Pi)/n]) + 
          I*Sin[(Arg[re + im*I] + 2*k*Pi)/n]}, {k, 0, n - 1}];
        zkList]
```

Example:

```
roots[1, 0, 4]
{1, I, -1, -I}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Lines between what points?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what is the aim. I post this as motivation. Apologies for errors and misunderstanding.  [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) and[`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) are useful for dynamic/interactive exploration. [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html) can allow you to explore different z. [`Slider2D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider2D.html) can also be useful.

Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{r = Norm[pt]^(1/n), pts}, 
  pts = Table[
    r {Cos[ArcTan @@ pt/n + 2 Pi j/n], 
      Sin[ArcTan @@ pt/n + 2 Pi j/n]}, {j, 0, n - 1}]; 
  Graphics[{Point[pt], Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[pts], Blue, 
    Circle[{0, 0}, Norm[pt]], Orange, FaceForm[None], 
    EdgeForm[Orange], Polygon[pts], Circle[{0, 0}, r], Black, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ pts, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]], {{pt, {1, 0}}, Locator}, {n, 
  Range[2, 7]}]
```

[image]

Comment: ‘Here’? Is that meant to be a hyperlink? I am happy to delete my answer.

Comment: Hello, thank for your post. Here is what I meant. 'Animate[ListPlot[zkList[[1 ;; i]], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Small}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {i, 1, n, 1}]' Unfortunately, it does not show line between first and last point. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Janukalado you could just modify your Table from 0 to n to repeat the first element and allow closure. Otherwise use Graphics and Polygon.